# Converting ASCII to int

Tags: arduino

Using an arduino Wifi library (model MKR1000), I'm receiving a value from a webpage. Of course the value I'm receiving is ascii, so Arduino is having trouble receiving it and making it into a number.

So basically, instead of 62 (the number that is on the webpage) I am receiving "5450" (where 54 is ASCII value for 6 and 50 is ASCII value for 2).

My code is

```
String c;
// By setting this to String it prints out 5450
// By setting this to int it instead prints out "hp"

if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
  Serial.println("connected to server");
  // Make a HTTP request:
  client.println("GET /arduino/electricity.php");
  delayNumber = 0;
}


  while (client.available()) {
    c = c + client.read();
  }
//Adds 54 and then 50 to c


Serial.print("C is: " + c);
//Currently prints 5450
```

I am completely lost. How can I make it so that my variable "c" is 62?

EDIT: I translated 54 and 50 using this table http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Silly to ask, why is 6 the DEC value of 54 and 2 the DEC value of 50?

Comment: It just is, I followed this reference for translation http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: That is ascii code, NOT DEC value. You should not make others misunderstand.

Comment: Sorry, edited now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.read()` will return integer in your case.

Try using this:

```
c += (char) client.read();
```

I only answered this based on my knowledge in java.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Okay this is returning a String with 62, so now I only need to convert that String to an int.

Comment: I used c.toInt() and now it's an int. You have no idea how much I love you right now.